# JQuery New Lines

Tags: jquery, html, newline

The code is supposed to add a new line of text every time the text is clicked. Isn't working with \n at all. With `<br/>` works just for the first click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickMe').click(function() {
    var oldText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(oldText +"\n Click added some text! ");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="clickMe">
      Click here!!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickMe').click(function() {
     var oldText = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(oldText +"\n Click added some text! ");
     });
 });
 </script>
 <body>
 <div id="clickMe">
     Click here!!
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
The whole code

Comment: use a `<br>` for newlines (and change `.text` to `.html`)

Comment: use html instead of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<br/>` as suggested in comments, but you have to use `html()` and not `text()`.

```
$(this).html(oldText +"<br/> Click added some text! ");
```

The difference is the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2):

> Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

(note **HTML**),
that is different from [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) that:

> Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code -

1. html newlines are `<br>`
2. you would need to change `.text` to `.html` to use the br:

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
  $(this).html(function(index, oldHtml) {  // use a function if you are appending then you don't need to get the old html seperately
    return oldHtml + "<br>Click added some text! "
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickMe">
  Click here!!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

using the

```
var oldText = $(this).html();
$(this).html(oldText +" <br/> Click added some text! ");
```

does solve the problem, but it's not a good solution, since the variable will grow with every click (since 'oldtext is growing with every click). and this is unneeded. 
use the `.append()` function instad:

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
  $(this).append(" <br> Click added some text! ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickMe').click(function() {
        var oldText = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(oldText +" <br/> Click added some text! ");
        });
    });
    </script>
    <body>
    <div id="clickMe">
        Click here!!
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    var oldText = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(oldText +"<br> Click added some text! ");
    });
});
```

replace `.text()` to `.html()` as if we use `<br>` and `html()` will render html components while `text()` just print out plain text